# Is there a way to append multiple list with the same value at once - Python

Tags: python, list, append

For my school project I'm trying to append a value to multiple lists at once.
An example of what I'm trying to do:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6]
```

Lets say I'm trying to add a 7 onto the end of both of them. Instead of doing:

```
list1.append(7)
list2.append(7)
```

Is there a way I can do this in one line. I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
(list1, list2).append(7)
```

Comment: No, there isn't. If you want to manipulate them in similar ways, you should probably put them in a common structure (a list, a dict) so that you can loop over them easily - and if they are related, let it be shown by the structure of your data rather than by giving them similar names.

Comment: How would you normally do the same task repeatedly, `for` each of a given list of values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a for loop. See below:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [3, 4, 6]
for i in (a,b):
    i.append(7)
    
print(a)
print(b)
```

This gives us:

```
[1, 2, 3, 7]
[3, 4, 6, 7]
```